# Qt - How validate a xml file with xsd file which imports another xsd file?

Tags: xml, qt, xsd

I use this code to validate my `foo.xml`

> ```
> QFile* fileXsd = new QFile("D:\\...\\fooValidator.xsd");
> if (!fileXsd->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
>     qWarning() << QObject::tr("Couldn't open xsd file.");    
> QXmlSchema schema;
> schema.load(fileXsd);
> if(schema.isValid()) 
> {
>     QFile* fileXml = new QFile("D:\\...\\foo.xml");
>     if (!fileXml->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
>         qWarning() << QObject::tr("Couldn't open xml file.");
>     QXmlSchemaValidator validator(schema);
>     if(!validator.validate(fileXml, QUrl::fromLocalFile(fileXml->fileName())))
>         qCritical() << "instance document is invalid";
>     else
>     {
>         //Ok
>     }
>  }
> ```

My file `fooValidator.xsd` imports types from a file `fooTypeValidator.xsd`.

`fooValidator.xsd`, `fooTypeValidator.xsd` and `foo.xml` are correct (I verrified with  [xmlvalidation](http://www.xmlvalidation.com))

When I run my program, I get an error ; the type declared in `fooTypeValidator.xsd` cannot be resolved.

`fooTypeValidator.xsd` is not imported by `QXmlSchema` nor by `QXmlSchemaValidator`

Comment: Have you tried using schemaValidator with no arguments? In that case it follows the link to the schema referenced by the xsi attribute. Maybe it will resolve the includes better?

Comment: With no arguments, I have the same problem.

Comment: ever find a workaround to this?

Comment: No, I get round the problem.